# Converting 3D array to 2D array removing unnecessary values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm analyzing data in search for number plate. I'm implementing vertical and horizontal projection. To do so I need 2D array but after initial preprocessing I have an 3D array looking like this:

> [ [
> [1, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 1],
>
> [row number 2 ], etc] ]

Each pixel is represented by array of lenght 3 containing same values(luminance).
I need only single value instead of array.
I'm new to python so I don't know any optimal method of doing so.

I was working with test image with 800x533 resolution.
Tried with answer found on other question but it didn't help me much as I don't understand matrix transformation well.
I don't want to use naive method creating new array from iterating the one I have as I believe there are faster methods.

That got me an array of shape (533, 2400)
Here is code i tried:

`transformed = input.reshape((input.shape[0], -1), order='F')`

I expect
array

> [[ [1,1,1], [1,1,1]...
>
> [2,2,2], [2,2,2]...] ]

after transformation would look like:

> [ [1, 1...],
>
> [2, 2...] ]

And has right dimensions size according to initial image resolution.
What should I look for?

Comment: Perhaps you could do `transformed[:,:transformed.shape[1]//3]`

Comment: By "you only need one value", you mean you just need one 800x533 layer out of three? Wouldn't `input[:, :, 0]` work? Or do you need to combine the layers somehow? Maybe putting explicitly the starting shape and ending shape you want would help

Comment: It seems that your image is in an RGB or YCrCb format and you want greyscale. Is that so?

Comment: Scott Staniewicz that looks like something I was looking for, and yes I need just one 800x533 layer.

Comment: Reti43 I didn't mention image format, Its extracted luminance from YUV then processed it into grayscale. But I don't think that format is a problem here.